# How to speed up conversion array of shorts to bitmap in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, performance, kotlin

I receive data from depth sensor using Vendor API. This API provides images in form of array of shorts, but original data from sensor is array of uint8, which is causing corruption of image and I need realign array to image be correctly displayed. Additionally I have to make coloring of this image to show depth on this image. This operations cause that it takes a lot of time on CPU and I can display only few frame per second. Is there any way to increased speed of this conversion?

I migrated from ImageView to SurfaceView, to take less time on UI thread and I'm executing this code on separated thread. Now UI is responsive, but still it takes almost 200-300ms to convert this frame to array of ints and color it and then convert it to bitmap.

```
    private fun getColors(value: Int, max: Int): IntArray {
        val rgb = IntArray(3)

        val range = value * 7 * 256 / max

        if (range < 256) {
            rgb[2] = range % 256
        } else if (range < 2 * 256) {
            rgb[1] = range % 256
            rgb[2] = 255
        } else if (range < 3 * 256) {
            rgb[1] = 255
            rgb[2] = 255 - range % 256
        } else if (range < 4 * 256) {
            rgb[0] = range % 256
            rgb[1] = 255
            rgb[2] = 0
        } else if (range < 5 * 256) {
            rgb[0] = 255
            rgb[1] = 255 - range % 256
        } else if (range < 6 * 256) {
            rgb[0] = 255
            rgb[1] = 0
            rgb[2] = range % 256
        } else {
            rgb[0] = 255
            rgb[1] = if(range > 7*255) 255 else range % 256
            rgb[2] = 255
        }

        return rgb
    }

    private fun updateDepthImage(depth: DepthImage): Bitmap {
        val table = depth.data //array of shorts
        val inttab = IntArray(table.size / 2)


    // Correct align of the table and convert it to table of Int 
        for (i in 0 until table.size / 2) {
            var sum = (table[2 * i].toInt() and 0xff) + (table[2 * i + 1].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8)//*255/2367;
            if (sum > 10000) {
                sum = 10000
            }
            inttab[i] = sum
        }
        val max = 10000

    // Color correction
        for (i in inttab.indices) {
            val rgb = getColors(inttab[i], max)
            val color = -0x1000000 or (rgb[0] shl 16) or (rgb[1] shl 8) or rgb[2]
            inttab[i] = color
        }

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(inttab, 640, 480, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

        return bitmap
    }
```